# Is it possible to exclude a recipient when sending to a Google/Gmail group?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-groups

We use Google Apps, and we have many groups of recipients.

Is it possible to send an email to a group, and exclude a certain recipient from that group? There is such an option in Outlook; is it possible in Gmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saariko, the short answer is no.

I assume you're talking about domain-wide Google Groups, not a group of contacts for a specific user. Since Google Groups is a separate service (rather poorly integrated into Gmail), the full membership of that group cannot be expanded and modified in the **To** field like it can in Outlook with Exchange.

However, an individual user's contact group *will* expand into individual email addresses when typed into the **To** field, and you can then remove any you wish. If the population of your group was relatively inflexible, you could mimic the domain group with an individual contact group to provide this functionality.

Answer (score 6):

If you click on the **Gmail** button and choose **Contacts** then choose your group, you can choose all members of that group and then selectively uncheck the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is Yes :)

You can create a [Content Compliance](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934) rule to prevent emails getting to certain Group members. In this example, I added the rule to the OU which has all users you do not want to receive the email.

- Internal Receiving
- Expression, If ANY of the following match the message

  > Location: Recipients Header
  >
  > Contains text "group@domain.com"
- If the above expressions match, do the following

  > [Reject|Quarantine message]
- Account types to affect

  > Users

Answer (score 2):

**larsen161** got me where I needed to go.

I wanted to exclude a User recipient from the "ALL" mailing group in my domain.
I followed **larsen161** instructions but I also had to activate the **Envelope filter** option with: **Only affect specific envelope recipients** , then in **Single email address** I added the recipient's email address I wanted to exclude.

I also had to check the "**Inbound**" option with "**Internal - receiving**" at **Email messages to affect**.

So now, every incoming emails sent to the **ALL** mailing list will never be delivered to the address I wanted to exclude. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. This is what worked for me.

1. In the Admin Console navigate to Apps > Google Workspace > Gmail
2. Go to the 'Compliance' section and add the 'Content Compliance' rule.
3. Select the options 'Inbound' and 'Internal - receiving'
4. In the section 'Add expressions that describe the content you want to search for in each message' choose:
   'If ALL of the following match the message'
   Click the 'Add' button beside 'Expressions'
5. Configure the expression as follows:
   Change 'Simple content match' to 'Advanced content match'
   In the 'Location' field, choose 'Full header'
   In the 'Match type' field, choose 'Contains text'
   In the 'Content' field enter "X-BeenThere: group@domain.com replacing the address with the address of the group in question. In my case it was all@mydomain.com
6. Click the 'Save' button
7. Click the 'Add' button once more to add another expression
8. Configure the expression as follows:
   Choose 'Advanced content match'
   In the 'Location' field, choose 'Full headers'
   For 'Match type,' select 'Contains text'
   In the 'Content' field, enter the email address of the user you want to exclude from the 'All users in the organization' group
9. Click the 'Save' button
10. Finally, after adding these expressions, in the third section labeled 'If the above expressions match, do the following' change the field 'Modify message' to 'Reject message'
11. Click the 'Save' button

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can but G Suite groups can include other groups as well as users so you can add different groups in an "everyone" group to make managing everything easier.

Example:

```
uk@domain.com
 - Fred
 - Jenny
 - Jess 
us@domain.com
 - Tom
 - Bill
 - Megan 
everyone@domain.com
 - uk@domain.com
 - us@domain.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Building off of Jordan's answer, that groups that are in your own contacts list do work in this desired way:

There's a tool that gives you the ability to sync such groups across multiple/all users of a G Suite Domain (and even across G Suite Domains if you buy the Pro licenses).  The tool is https://www.gmailsharedcontacts.com/

Once you sign up with them, you can create groups and sync them to a select users in your G Suite domain.  **Then** each of these users **will** have the ability to compose an email to that contacts group and then optionally remove individual email addresses.

Handy!