# Remove single user from "everyone" list

Tags: email, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

We are using Google Apps and want to remove one of the email addresses from the "everyone" list. Imagine a helpdesk ticket being created every time someone sends an email to everyone.

What options do I have in accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to exclude accounts of the domain of the everyone list.

From [Add all users to a group - G Suite Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/66338?hl=en)

> You can't edit the members within the All users within your-domain
>   member. But just like any other group, you can edit the groups access
>   settings or delete it.

Note: On 2018-07-17 the above quote continue being valid.

Instead, create a group to which you add the desired members by other means. There are several options for that.

Another note: Suspended users will not receive emails sent to a "everyone" list.

Comment: This answer is not useful. When your GApps domain includes both real people and robots, you don't want to have to keep a parallel group updated over years as people join and leave the company.

Comment: @RossPresser Your comment looks like a criticism that should be pointed to Google and perhaps it should derivate on a feature request.

Answer (score -1):

It should be possible to do this now, using Content Compliance. See this answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/122559